# Looking for android samples using Java and C++

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to find out some samples demonstrating how to write an android app using combination of `Java` and `C++`. I have found a lot of examples based on `Java` and `C` but I am looking for `Java` and `C++`.

To be specific, I am looking for some samples where `Java` code calls some `C++` code and `C++` code calls some `Java` code.

I don't have much experience in `Java` and `C++`.

Can anyone point me to any sample/tutorial/demo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Android specific example in JNIpp library: https://github.com/DmitrySkiba/itoa-jnipp/tree/master/android/samples There are also generic examples in help section: http://dmitryskiba.github.com/itoa-jnipp/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out android NDK example folder for native-audio